# All files read-only after compiling OpenFlipper, subsequently unable to boot into Linux at all

Tags: linux, make

I tried compiling OpenFlipper on Linux Mint with `make -j8`, however this failed (unable to write a file) and left me with an operating system where I wasn't able to save ANY files (text, screenshots, ..).

After reboot I'm unable to get into Linux but instead see a black basic full-screen shell with the message "Failed to find cpu0 device node".

---

This has happened to me on at least 3 separate occasions so it should be related to OpenFlipper or at least using `make`. Is OpenFlipper bricking my computer, or is my SSD unable to handle having so many bits written to it at once, or what else is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to say what caused this but at least how to fix it.

Run `fsck /dev/sda6` (replace `/dev/sda6` with your system's root (`/`) directory) and agree to all the inode changes it proposes (press `y`), this will give you back a bootable OS.

If instead you're still in your system (ie you haven't rebooted yet after seeing the "read-only" message) you can run `sudo fsck /dev/sda6` from your usual terminal, however you will still have to reboot to regain a working OS.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the default action of a failed filesystem ext* is to drop into read/only mode.  Thus you might be seeing is either your disk hardware is starting to fail -OR- you have exercised some type of issue that causes filesystem corruption.

Once you are in read/only mode your only recourse is to reboot and let fsck try to fix the problem.  If the filesystem structure is VERY corrupt you may not get a bootable system back depending on what partition we are talking about.  Then it is time for rebuilding the system and using those trusty backups.

Comment: How is a non-sudo'd command able to cause filesystem corruption? Doesn't Linux rights management prevent that?

My hardware is very new so I don't think that's it.